# Snap SVG: Using 'for loop' to Transform/Translate x-position

Tags: svg, transform, snap.svg

Using snap.svg.js. Trying to translate the xPos but nothing happens.

Here is the example *jsfiddle.net/hswuhdj4*

```
window.objectPool = {
    rectQ1: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue}),
    rectQ2: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue}),
    rectQ3: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue}),
    rectQ4: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue}),
    rectQ5: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue}),
    rectQ6: paper.rect(0,0,0, svgHeight).attr({fill:lighterBlue})
}
```

I use an objectpool so i can reuse my objects to keep performance.

```
window.rectsQ = [
    objectPool.rectQ1,
    objectPool.rectQ2,
    objectPool.rectQ3,
    objectPool.rectQ4,
    objectPool.rectQ5,
    objectPool.rectQ6
];
```

pushing them in an Array rectsQ for easy future access

```
var rectAmount = 6;
var rectWidth = 100;

for(i=0;i<rectAmount;i++){
    paper.node.appendChild(window.rectsQ[i].node); //immitates toFront() function of Raphael.
    window.rectsQ[i].attr({width:rectWidth}); //assigning a width
    window.rectsQ[i].transform('T' + (svgWidth-(rectWidth*(i+1))) + ' 0');
}
```

First, I call the object back to the front, then assign a width, finally translate the x-pos, to the right side of the svg-tag.

It doesn't seem too difficult, but for some reason, no matter what transform i do, the object doesn't move.

```
//It stays right at these coordinates:
x = 0, 
y = 0

//while it should be moved to:
x = svgWidth-rectWidth,
y = 0
```

I've tried using a Relative Translation ('t') instead of absolute Translation ('T'). No luck though.
Does anyone have an idea to why these snap objects won't move, and how to fix it?

Removing the 2 extra arguments helped in the JSFiddle i made, but weirdly enough not in my project.
This is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hswuhdj4/3

FIXED!!
What caused the problem was the local snap.svg.js file.
Changing the directory with the link *raw.githubusercontent.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/master/dist/snap.svg-min.js* fixed the problem for me.

Does anyone know how this occurred?

Comment: Really I think you need to put the example on a jsfiddle, and it will probably be a lot more straightforward to check. I do think Robert is correct though, remove that 0 0 and I think it 'should' work. I suspect its because it doesn't like the format of the transform string rather than it transforming back though.

Comment: Already removed the 2 arguments. this is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hswuhdj4/3/. It works in the fiddle but weirdly enough not in my project

Answer (score 0):

Transform usually takes 2 arguments. I.e. T x y you're giving it 4 though.

The documentation says it works like paths, and if so T x y 0 0 would be the same as T x y T 0 0 which would move the rect to x y and then move it back again to 0 0.

Comment: It's true that translate only needs 2 arguments, while it's untrue that the 2 extra args would overwrite the 2 first ones, but rather ignore them instead.

I've used 4 arguments throughout the whole project thinking that the last 2 arguments were cx and cy (always setting them as cx cy 0 0.)

Nowhere else in the project have they caused trouble.

Also removing them hasn't solved anything. but thanks for helping :)